# sip-install failing with exit code 1 and an unclear error message

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I'm trying to run pyqtdeploy and am getting an unclear error message. I downloaded all of the dependencies and tried to build the demo application with:

```
python build-demo.py --verbose
```

```
Running 'make install'.
/home/argosopentech/run/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake -install qinstall libsip.a /home/argosopentech/run/demo/sysroot-linux-64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/libsip.a
PyQt: installing component...
PyQt: looking for 'pyqt-commercial.sip' in /home/argosopentech/run/demo.
PyQt: looking for 'PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz' in /home/argosopentech/run/demo.
PyQt: reading 'https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/5.15.2/'.
PyQt: downloading 'PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz' from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6c/640e3f5c734c296a7193079a86842a789edb7988dca39eab44579088a1d1/...
PyQt: downloaded 'https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6c/640e3f5c734c296a7193079a86842a789edb7988dca39eab44579088a1d1/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz'.
PyQt: copying /home/argosopentech/.pyqtdeploy/cache/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz to /home/argosopentech/run/demo/sysroot-linux-64/build.
PyQt: unpacking 'PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz'.
Running 'sip-install --qmake /home/argosopentech/run/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake --no-distinfo --concatenate 2 --no-docstrings --verbose'.
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
/home/argosopentech/run/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake -query
This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.15.2 (licensed under the GNU General Public License) for Python 3.8.5 on linux.
Found the license file 'pyqt-gpl.sip'.
These bindings will be built: QtCore, QtNetwork, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtX11Extras.
Generating the QtCore bindings...
Generating the QtNetwork bindings...
Generating the QtGui bindings...
Generating the QtWidgets bindings...
Generating the QtX11Extras bindings...
Generating the .pro file for the QtCore module...
Generating the .pro file for the QtNetwork module...
Generating the .pro file for the QtGui module...
Generating the .pro file for the QtWidgets module...
Generating the .pro file for the QtX11Extras module...
Generating the top-level .pro file...
Generating the Makefiles...
/home/argosopentech/run/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake -recursive PyQt5.pro
sip-install: '/home/argosopentech/run/demo/sysroot-linux-64/Qt/bin/qmake -recursive PyQt5.pro' failed returning 3
Info: creating stash file /tmp/tmp0u30e4ly/.qmake.stash
Reading /tmp/tmp0u30e4ly/QtCore/QtCore.pro
Reading /tmp/tmp0u30e4ly/QtNetwork/QtNetwork.pro
Reading /tmp/tmp0u30e4ly/QtGui/QtGui.pro
Reading /tmp/tmp0u30e4ly/QtWidgets/QtWidgets.pro
Reading /tmp/tmp0u30e4ly/QtX11Extras/QtX11Extras.pro
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: x11extras
pyqtdeploy-sysroot: execution of 'sip-install' failed: returned exit code 1
```

[Full code](https://github.com/PJ-Finlay/pyqtdeploy/tree/0cfd5a620f612044acb0c8634c8246410373560d)

Comment: The problem is that you are missing the "x11extras" module, how did you install Qt? Have you used the online installer or the repositories of your OS?

Comment: I tried installing qt `sudo apt-get install qt5-default ` but got the same error. I'm trying to build qt from source as part of pyqtdeploy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install PyQt x11extras for Python3 which is its own Debian package:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pyqt5.qtx11extras
```